Can someone identify if this time series is seasonal or cyclical?
I am trying to forecast and analyse the next 5 days of a time series but am having trouble finding what models to use as i'm not exactly sure if this is cyclical or seasonal. Its a basic question, but the graph i have isn't exactly similar to the examples i've read up on as it has a quadratic positive trend.
Can someone identify and explain why its cyclical or seasonal?

